# ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called : "PUBLIC.PLITBLM"

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, package, ibatis

I have a java web app that calls the oracle plsql procedure from ibatis xml file. this procedure captures the audit information of the table. so when multiple users modifies a table  this stored procedure .after certain time i receive the following error.

> --- The error occurred in example.xml.
>   --- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
>   --- Check the example.params.
>   Check the statement (update procedure failed).
>   Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded
>   ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped stored procedure "PUBLIC.PLITBLM" 
>   ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
>   "PUBLIC.PLITBLM"  ORA-06512: at "AUDIT", line 279
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

call from ibatis

> {call AUDIT(?,?,?,?,?,?,'val')}

call from java web app

> Map _temp = new HashMap(params);
>   _temp.put("OPERATION_TYPE",operation);
>   sqlMapper.insert("call_proc_audit",_temp);
>   return false;

The plsql procedure has only execute immediate for insert,update and delete.

I have removed the code due to security.

Comment: Post the fragment of code, where you call this procedure.

Comment: @David: i have posted the code.

Comment: No, you haven't. Where is this FRDWEB.AUDIT procedure, mentioned in error message? You posted FRDWEB.WF_CMD_HIST_VER_AUDIT_ENTRY.

Comment: @SureshSankar, does your plsql function compiles succefully?

Comment: @A.B yes successfully compiled and execute from sqlplus. when calling with java after certain time i get this error.

Comment: David,a.b,APC : thanks for your efforts. i am removing the plsql code due to security.

Comment: You should remove the `WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;`.  That loses the error stack and then you can't find the real line number with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PLITBLM package is part of the standard Oracle build; apparently it handles index organized tables.  It's not documented in any detail because it's not something we need to call directly.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a68001/intro.htm)  It's likely that some standard Oracle functionality has dependencies on it.

As to why your program hurls that exception, that's a bit of a facer.  The package is created by a script in the Oracle home `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/plitblm.sql`.  However, it cannot be run on its own but only as part of `catproc,sql`.  This builds the data dictionary and other things, and is run as part of the Oracle installation process.

Perhaps you have a botched install?

Interestingly, the actual PLITBLM package is owned by SYS but the error message references PUBLIC, which suggests it might just be a missing public synonym.  However, if `catproc,sql` has not run successfully there may be other lurking nasties.  You really need a DBA to check the database, and if necessary re-run `catproc,sql`.

Comment: APC:Thank you very much.i will talk to my DBA.